# Does a chain of three finitely-generated abelian groups admit compatible bases?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ be a chain of finitely generated abelian groups. Is it always possible to find compatible bases for these three groups?

By this, I mean $\mathbf{Z}$-bases $\{a_i\}$ of $A$, $\{b_j\}$ of $B$, and $\{c_k\}$ of $C$ such that each $b_j$ is an integer multiple of a single $c_k$ and similarly each $a_i$ is an integer multiple of a single $b_j$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: That is not always possible even with just two such groups $A \le B$.

Comment: You know it is possible for $A\subset B$ free finitely generated abelian groups. So maybe you want to add the extra condition free?

Comment: With free abelian groups it is not always possible with $A \le B \le C$ (that follows from my previous comment).